# Editing Font Size in Sun Studio 11

Tags: sunstudio

How can I change the font size for all the windows in Sun Studio 11?  The text in all the windows is very tiny.  I can't read the help in the program.

One method is to start the program with --fontsize  - found this through Googling.. but how can you do it in the IDE itself?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is very small though,Try

> `--fontsize <size>`parameter of the sunstudio start script.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out now that I can read the menus.  It's under Tools->Options->Editor Options